# How do you use BigInteger?

Tags: java

How do you use BigInteger exactly? I'm trying to do the following:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class hello{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       for(int i = 0; i <= 1024; i++){
           BigInteger a = new BigInteger(Math.pow(2,i));
           System.out.println(a);
       }
   }
}
```

I want `a` to hold this potentially huge value so that I can manipulate it in the program.

Comment: Have you read the BigInteger documentation in the corresponding JavaDoc? That's a better place to start than asking a question in StackOverflow. Don't you think?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about what it already says in the Javadoc and exhibits zero prior research

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any prior research on this topic. This is basic.

Answer (score 5):

`Math.pow` returns a `double` and `2^i` cannot be represented in a `double` as it is way too big.

You need to use the `pow` method from `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java's Math class does not have methods of BigInteger.
Use BigInteger's method instead.

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger(Math.pow(2,i));
System.out.println(a);
```

should be

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2").pow(i); // String to BigInteger, and then power
System.out.println(a);
```

or

```
BigInteger a = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(i); // long to BigInteger, and then power
System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `BigInteger(double)` constructor. Try using `new BigInteger(String)` and instead of `Math.pow` use `BigInteger#pow` method which also returns `BigInteger`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2").pow(i);
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of BigInteger like a string. You can't use any of the arithmetic, relational, and unary operators on it like you would do for primitive data types. Instead, you have to use the methods inside the `BigInteger` class to perform operations on BigInteger.
For example, if you wanted to multiply two BigIntegers, you can't do this:

```
BigInteger a = (new BigInteger("5"))*(new BigInteger("7"));
```

Instead, you must declare two BigIntegers and then multiply them with `.multiply()`

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("5");//note how these numbers are like strings
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("7");
BigInteger c = a.multiply(b);
```

So in regards to your program where you want to print the powers of two, you have to use BigInteger in a slightly different way.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 1024; i++){
       BigInteger a = new BigInteger("2").pow(i);
       System.out.println(a);
   }
```

Note how the value inside the `.pow()` is an `int`. That's specified in the BigInteger [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Essentially, BigInteger is a very powerful tool when calculating large values, but it is also more tedious and requires lengthier and more involved code.